# why doesn't it terminate?

Tags: algorithm, scala, syntax

```
  var m_root : Node = root
  private def insert(key: Int, value: Int): Node = {
        if(m_root == null) {
            m_root = Node(key, value, null, null)
        }
        var t : Node = m_root
        var flag : Int = 1
        while (t != null && flag == 1) {
            if(key == t.key) {
                t
            }
            else if(key < t.key) {
                if(t.left == null) {
                    t.left = Node(key, value, null, null)
                    flag = 0
                } else {
                    t = t.left
                }

            } else {
                if(t.right == null) {
                    t.right = Node(key, value, null, null)
                    flag = 0
                } else {
                    t = t.right
                }
            }
        }
      t
 }
```

I wrote iterative version insert a node to binary search tree. I want to terminate when node is created, but it doesn't stop, because I think I didn't assign terminating condition. How to I edit my code to terminate when a node inserted in?

Comment: "insult of binary search tree"? Couldn't agree more.

Comment: On a point of style: your code would be slightly clearer if you renamed `flag` to `carryOn`, and made it a boolean variable that was initially `true` but had `false` assigned to it when you want to terminate the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what behaviour you want, but the cause is quite clear.

Your loop is a `while` condition, which will loop until `t` is `null`.  So while `t` is non-null the loop will continue.

You only ever assign `t` to non-null values - in fact you're *specifically* checking for the null case and stopping it happening by creating a new node.

So either you need to reconsider your loop condition, or ensure `t` does in fact become null in some cases, depending on what your actual algorithm requirements are.

And since you're returning `t` at the bottom, I suggest the while condition is wrong; the only possible way this could terminate is if `t` is null at this point, so it would be pointless to return this anyway.

Comment: I edit my code cos, inspired your comment, but It cannot terminate itself.

Comment: @Jaehyun (based on your edit) - Think about what happens in the common case, where the node already exists.  You aren't correctly setting the `flag` to zero in the termination case within the first `if` block, so at that point it will still spin around the `while` loop forever.

Comment: Also I agree with dave4420 that this should be a `boolean` flag with a better name.  And additionally, since you now has a flag that definitively determines whether to continue or not, there's no reason to also include the `t != null` check in your `while` condition.

Answer (score 4):

The first clause of your "if" statement in the loop

```
if(key == t.key) {
    t
}
```

... does nothing if the comparison is true.  It doesn't terminate the loop.  The statement `t` is not synonymous with `return t` here.  You can set `flag = 0` at that point to terminate the loop.